# Accessing objects in a ruby struct. Can find the object but cannot call method on the struct

Tags: ruby, struct

```
class ScrapeJob < Struct.new(:scrape_id) 
    def perform
      @scrape = Scrape.find(scrape_id)
      puts @scrape.link
    end
end
```

Why can I find this object `@scrape` but I cannot ask it for any of it's attributes in this `struct`. `@scrape.link` is just a string and console returns an error that I cannot call a private method. How can I get this objects info?

Comment: I think you are leaving out key information needed to answer this question. What is  the `Scrape` class? What is its `link` method?

Comment: the class scrape is a regular model and link is a regular attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are forgetting to give your Struct a name, so `scrape_id` becomes the name class name.  The syntax you probably want to use is:

```
ScrapeJob = Struct.new(:scrape_id) do
   ...
end
```